# Regex matching for variables and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match variables and numbers in a javascript string (surrounding matches with span tags).

I'm having issues with variables in the form x1, c2 etc.   My code originally looked like this

```
output = output.replace(/\d+/g,"<span class=\"number\">$&</span>");
output = output.replace(/\)/g,"<span class=\"function\">$&</span>");
output = output.replace(/[a-zA-Z]+\d*/g,returnTextValue); 
//returnTextValue is a function checking whether the string is a variable or plain text
//and highlighting accordingly
```

This caused variables in the form [a-zA-Z]+\d+ to not get matched correctly, because they had already been replaced with the number tag.

I've been trying a few things using lookaheads and stuff like `[^A-Za-z]?\d+` for the numbers, but have not been able to find a good way of doing this.

I know I could match the tags, but would like a more elegant solution.

Am I missing an obvious logical solution, or does somebody have a regex operator I don't know for this situation?

Comment: Is the `\d+` in the first rule supposed to match isolated numbers?  Add boundaries `\b\d+\b`, then it won't match the `a2` type.

Comment: that worked great, thank you.  If you put it as an answer I will certainly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the \d+ in the first rule supposed to match isolated numbers? Add boundaries \b\d+\b, then it won't match the a2 type. – [Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski) Dec 6 at 2:55